# Passing numbers, variables, and procedures as arguments in Java

Tags: java, argument-passing

I just started studying how to code in the Java programming language.

I was given a problem that told me to pass numbers, variables, and expressions as arguments to a procedure call. The problem I am having is that I get an error when I tried to pass numbers, variables and expressions as arguments to the procedure call (I got 27 errors).

Below is my code, and I would really appreciate it if anyone could point out what is wrong with my code. Thank you.

```
public class test {

// this is the procedure definition
public static int computeCost ( int quantity , int price ) {
    return quantity * price;
}

public static void main ( String args[] ) 
    // passing numbers as arguments to the procedure call "cost"
    System.out.println ( computeCost ( 7 , 12 ) );

    // passing variables as arguments to the procedure call "cost"
    int a = 5;
    int b = 7;
    System.out.println ( computeCost ( a , b ) );

    // passing expressions as arguments to the procedure call "cost
    System.out.println ( computeCost ( 1 + 2 + 3 + 4, 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 ) );
}
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Yep, as per @kon's suggestion, the error message will likely tell you exactly what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I am working on the command prompt (cmd) and the errors I am getting are "error: ';' expected", "error: <identifier> expected", and "error: illegal start of type".

Comment: Usually the error indicates the line number... that's a good place to start looking. Pretty sure that the three people who independently noticed the lack of `{` at the start of the definition of `main` are on to something. Once that's missing, the compiler goes nuts trying to make sense of things.

Comment: @Floris. Thank you. I will take note of your advice.

Comment: Also, since it's clear you're learning the language, any reason you're not using an IDE like Eclipse? These sorts of problems would rarely occur in an IDE!

Comment: @Kon. Yes. Actually, I am using BlueJ and Ecplipse. But for this particular problem, I used the command prompt to train myself get used to compiling and solving questions using the command prompt.

Comment: Fair enough, good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the opening `{` in your definition of `main`!

```
public static void main ( String args[] )
```

should be

```
public static void main ( String args[] ) {
```

Comment: Genius. Thank you for pointing that out. I hate it when things like "this" happen. :)

Answer (score 5):

I see what's wrong. You don't have an opening bracket after your main(..) method. All methods in Java must have their code surrounded with `{` and `}`.

Change this:

```
public static void main ( String args[] )
```

to this:

```
public static void main ( String args[] ) {
```

Other than that your code looks perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an opening bracket on your main method.

```
public class Test
{
    // this is the procedure definition
    public static int computeCost(int quantity, int price)
    {
        return quantity * price;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {// <--MISSING
        // passing numbers as arguments to the procedure call "cost"
        System.out.println(computeCost(7, 12));

        // passing variables as arguments to the procedure call "cost"
        int a = 5;
        int b = 7;
        System.out.println(computeCost(a, b));

        // passing expressions as arguments to the procedure call "cost
        System.out.println(computeCost(1 + 2 + 3 + 4, 5 + 6 + 7 + 8));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip. Sometimes too many errors just corresponds to a missing piece of code.
Look for every possible cases.